# Value of type 'ContentView' has no member flag Tapped' and Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder'

Tags: swift, swiftui

Could someone check the following code and at least make it zero compiler errors. Currently, it has two compiler errors, which are "Value of type 'ContentView' has no member flag Tapped" and "Closure containing a declaration cannot be used with result builder 'ViewBuilder".

Thank you

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var calculusians = ["Bernhard Riemann", "Brook Taylor", "Colin Maclaurin", "Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz", "Guillaume de l'Hôpital", "Isaac Newton", "Johann Bernoulli", "Joseph-Louis Lagrange", "Leonhard Euler"].shuffled()
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack  {
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Image(self.calculusians[number])
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.flagTapped(number)
                            
                            
                        }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(calculusians[correctAnswer]))
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"), buttons: [.default(Text("Continue"))])
                }
            }
        }
        func flagTapped( tag: Int) {
            if tag == correctAnswer {
                // they were right!
                score += 1
                alertTitle = "Correct"
            } else {
                //they were wrong!
                score -= 1
                alertTitle = "Wrong"
            }
            
            showingAlert = true
        }
        
        func askQuestion() {
            calculusians.shuffled()
            correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put function outside the body var.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var calculusians = ["Bernhard Riemann", "Brook Taylor", "Colin Maclaurin", "Gottfried Wilhelm Leibniz", "Guillaume de l'Hôpital", "Isaac Newton", "Johann Bernoulli", "Joseph-Louis Lagrange", "Leonhard Euler"].shuffled()
    @State private var correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    
    @State private var score = 0
    @State private var alertTitle = ""
    @State private var showingAlert = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack  {
                ForEach(0..<3) { number in
                    Image(self.calculusians[number])
                        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            self.flagTapped(tag: number)
                        }
                }
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(calculusians[correctAnswer]))
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text(alertTitle), message: Text("Your score is \(score)"), buttons: [.default(Text("Continue"))])
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func flagTapped( tag: Int) {
        if tag == correctAnswer {
            // they were right!
            score += 1
            alertTitle = "Correct"
        } else {
            //they were wrong!
            score -= 1
            alertTitle = "Wrong"
        }
        
        showingAlert = true
    }
    
    func askQuestion() {
        calculusians.shuffled()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
    }
}
```